# Is it possible to prevent the user from submitting a form using the address bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've searched the web and not really found a solution to this so don't think it is possible. For further clarification though I will still ask the question.

Is it possible to prevent the user from submitting a form using the address bar?

For example:

```
javascript:document.forms[0].submit()
```

Typing the above into the address bar does nothing in Firefox but submitted the form no problem at all in Google Chrome without running my validation. For all I know this could be a bug with webkit or Google Chrome. The amount of people that will actually try this out is probably few but nonetheless this is an annoying issue that I'd like to solve if possible.

Here's a jsfiddle that better explains my problem (you'll have to copy the text into a blank html file and open it locally for it to work)

http://jsfiddle.net/b4DGj/9/

Copy the text into a blank html file and open it in a browser (preferably Google Chrome)

type:

```
javascript:document.forms[0].submit()
```

into the address bar and you will instantly be taken to Google without the javascript function being called

Firefox does nothing and Internet Explorer doesn't do much either Google Chrome will submit the form no problem at all though taking you to https://www.google.com/?#q= (which for some reason decides to throw a 404 error)

Comment: One can always send invalid data to your server, one does not need to use the form on your html page at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s not really possible to stop that. You can make it harder, but never impossible to get around. A user has full control over their client. Validate everything server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Chrome (in its default configuration) will try to look for whatever you throw on the address bar (that is not an actual address). https://www.google.com/?#q= is the standard search query for google. if you go to the setting area -> manage search engines you will find the standard queries for different search engines (if you have more than one).

Hope this helps.